# Make it easier with color changing

Tags: delphi

How can I simplify this in Delphi?

```
Procedure colori1
Begin

 if Temperatura<=15 then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=clBlue;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=clBlue;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=clBlue;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=clBlue;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=clBlue;
 end;

 if (Temperatura>=16) and (Temperatura<=18) then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=clAqua;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=clAqua;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=clAqua;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=clAqua;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=clAqua;
 end;

 if (Temperatura>=19) and (Temperatura<=22) then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=clLime;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=clLime;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=clLime;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=clLime;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=clLime;
 end;

 if (Temperatura>=23) and (Temperatura<=26) then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=clYellow;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=clYellow;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=clYellow;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=clYellow;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=clYellow;
 end;

 if (Temperatura>=27) and (Temperatura<=29) then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=$000080FF;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=$000080FF;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=$000080FF;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=$000080FF;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=$000080FF;
 end;

 if Temperatura>=30 then
 begin
  Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=clRed;
  Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=clRed;
  Form1.Label3.Font.Color:=clRed;
  Form1.Label4.Font.Color:=clRed;
  Form1.Label5.Font.Color:=clRed;
 end;
end;
```

If I use "for cycle" like this:

```
For i:=0 to n do label[i].font.color:=clRed
```

I'll obviously get an error, because Delphi doesn't know what `label[i]` means. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

Declare a local variable to hold the color:

```
var
  Color: TColor;
```

Then decide what the color should be:

```
if Temperatura<=15 then
  Color:=clBlue;
else if Temperatura<=18 then
  Color:=clAqua;
else ...
```

Then assign the color to the controls:

```
Form1.Label1.Font.Color:=Color;
Form1.Label2.Font.Color:=Color;
....
```

The labels could be stored in an array or a list. So that you can iterate over them to assign the color. You could declare the array like this, in the form class:

```
FLabels: TArray<TLabel>;
```

In the constructor assign it like this:

```
FLabels := TArray<TLabel>.Create(Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5);
```

To iterate over it setting the color do this:

```
var
  lbl: Tlabel;
....
for lbl in FLabels do
  lbl.Font.Color:=Color;
```

You appear to be using a global variable `Form1`. Your code will be better without that global variable, and having this procedure (and others like it) converted into a method of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Set the ParentFont property of each label to true in the IDE object inspector.

Then just set the Font property of their parent control (i.e. the Form or Panel they live in ). E.g:

```
if Temperatura <= 15 then
  Form1.Font.Color := clBlue;

if (Temperatura >= 16) and (Temperatura <= 18) then
  Form1.Font.Color:=clAqua;
```

etc.

Put them in a Panel if you like, to separate these labels from other controls which should not be affected.